# Change CSS Class of All previous <li> when i hover some other item

Tags: jquery, css

what i need, might be quite simple to do with jQuery, I just suck at it :/

I have this Unordered List list of years, what i want to do is, to change ALL css classes of the previous List Items when I Hover another item.

For example, in this image below, if I place the mouse at "1904" I want to change the css class of 1901, 1902 and 1903.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) to get all previous siblings and then use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to add/remove a class on [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), like this:

```
$("li").hover(function() {
  $(this).prevAll("li").toggleClass("myClass");
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/2mU3p/1/) note that it *doesn't* style the hovered element, only the previous ones, if you want to style the hovered `<li>` as well, [you can do this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/2mU3p/2/):

```
$("li").hover(function() {
  $(this).prevAll("li").andSelf().toggleClass("myClass");
});
```

In this case we're using [`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) to include the `<li>` being hovered in the set.